# AIrflow MySql connection Issues

Tags: mysql, airflow

I have **MySQL** and **airflow** instance both running on docker.

I am trying to test connection using query from **"data profiling > adhoc query"** options, but I am getting the below error. I have done the connections using **"admin > connections"**

***(2006, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")***

[connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJZXi.png)
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Etg.png)

I have connected the above using "localhost" as host i have exposed the mysql port to the hostmachine.

Also i have tried connecting using the IP and port. But it shows the below error.

***(2006, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")***

Although I can connect postgres instance running in another container without any problems.

I have a workaround to connect to **mysql** using **jdbc mysql** drivers but i am curious to see what is this problem.

Comment: Try to see the privileges of your user, you need to allow connect from  user@host_IP or user@%. Your user probably looks lie user@localhost, and that won't let you connect